# The type 'T' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable<T>'

Tags: c#, generics, nullable

Why am I getting this error in the following code?

```
void Main()
{
    int? a = 1;
    int? b = AddOne(1);
    a.Dump();
}

static Nullable<int> AddOne(Nullable<int> nullable)
{
    return ApplyFunction<int, int>(nullable, (int x) => x + 1);
}

static Nullable<T> ApplyFunction<T, TResult>(Nullable<T> nullable, Func<T, TResult> function)
{
    if (nullable.HasValue)
    {
        T unwrapped = nullable.Value;
        TResult result = function(unwrapped);
        return new Nullable<TResult>(result);
    }
    else
    {
        return new Nullable<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the question??

Comment: Can't test it right now, but you call `ApplyFunction<int, int>` instead of `ApplyFunction<int?, int>`?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Seems like a sound question to me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are several problems with the code. The first one is that your types must be nullable. You can express that by specifying `where T: struct`. You will also need to specify `where TResult: struct` because you're using that as a nullable type too.

Once you fix up the `where T: struct where TResult: struct` you also need to change the return value type (which was wrong) and a number of other things too.

After fixing all those errors and simplifying, you wind up with this:

```
static TResult? ApplyFunction<T, TResult>(T? nullable, Func<T, TResult> function)
                where T: struct 
                where TResult: struct
{
    if (nullable.HasValue)
        return function(nullable.Value);
    else
        return null;
}
```

Note that you can rewrite `Nullable<T>` as `T?` which makes things more readable.

Also you could write that as one statement using `?:` but I don't think it's as readable:

```
return nullable.HasValue ? (TResult?) function(nullable.Value) : null;
```

---

You might want to put this into an extension method:

```
public static class NullableExt
{
    public static TResult? ApplyFunction<T, TResult>(this T? nullable, Func<T, TResult> function)
        where T: struct
        where TResult: struct
    {
        if (nullable.HasValue)
            return function(nullable.Value);
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Then you can write code like this:

```
int? x = 10;
double? x1 = x.ApplyFunction(i => Math.Sqrt(i));
Console.WriteLine(x1);

int? y = null;
double? y1 = y.ApplyFunction(i => Math.Sqrt(i));
Console.WriteLine(y1);
```

Comment: Instead of writing `new TResult?()`, isn't it more clear to just write `null`? That's the philosophy of `Nullable<>`, I guess.

Comment: Instead of: return nullable.HasValue ? (TResult?) function(nullable.Value) : null; you could do return nullable??null; which is a bit nicer and more readable

Comment: @SteveTemple How then does `function()` get called?

Comment: Sorry misread the line, you're right if you want to call a function that won't work

Comment: you state that `return nullable.HasValue ? (TResult?) function(nullable.Value) : null;` isn't so readable (which i agree), but if you add a parameter to that extension method: `, TResult resultWhenNull = default(TResult)` then you can make the method body a lot more readable with `return (nullable.HasValue) ? function(nullable.Value) : resultWhenNull;`. Plus it adds a feature: you can specify the default value when your nullable is null, but it's only an optional parameter, so it's not an inconvenience that must always be passed. ;)

Comment: @ShawnKovac Your proposed `resultWhenNull` is of type `TResult` which isn't a nullable type, which means you couldn't return a null from the method. Did you mean to make it type `TResult?` ?

Comment: @MatthewWatson thanks, i coded it the way i expressed in my method, but as you so correctly pointed out, that's not what i really wanted. i have now corrected my code so the new parameter is `, TResult? resultWhenNull = null`. Thanks!!

Comment: so my full method is: `public static TResult? ApplyFunc<T, TResult>(this T? nullable, Func<T, TResult> function, TResult? resultWhenNull = null)
   where T : struct
   where TResult : struct
  { return (nullable.HasValue) ? function(nullable.Value) : resultWhenNull; }`

Comment: so i think the body of that method now is more readable than if an `if` statement were used. ;) thanks for that correction, Matthew! i quite appreciate it!

Comment: i just want to pipe in how nice C# is to us to forgive the omission of new lines where my code is all run together on one line, due to the comment restriction in this forum. i say 'phew!' that this is not a VB question! ;)

Comment: @ShawnKovac Yep, that's a nice addition. :)

Answer (score 7):

As the error suggests, the compiler has no guarantee that T won't already be nullable. You need to add a constraint to T:

```
static Nullable<T> ApplyFunction<T, TResult>(Nullable<T> nullable, 
    Func<T, TResult> function) : where T : struct 
                                 where TResult : struct
```

Comment: You'll need more changes than that to make it work. For example, TResult needs to be a struct too.

Comment: True, missed the `TResult?` fixed :)