# The type 'MyObject' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable<T>'

Tags: c#, generics

I'm using `.net framework 4.5`

I get the following error

> Error CS0453  The type 'MyObject' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable'

```
  public async Task<Nullable<MyObject>> MyMethod(string myParamter)
    {}
```

I also tried

```
  public async Task<MyObject?> MyMethod(string myParamter)
    {}
```

If I set the thing as nullable then why do I get the red line below the method name with this error message

The stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730753/the-type-t-must-be-a-non-nullable-value-type-in-order-to-use-it-as-parameter) is easy, make the return type nullable but for me Visual studio doesn't allow it.

Comment: `Nullable` is used only with non-nullable value types, to allow the value type to allow null. Reference types allow null values by default.

Comment: `public class MyObject`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Since `MyObject` is an object, and objects are nullable by definition, there is no use to use the `Nullable<T>` struct or `?` operator in order to support null values.

`Nullable<T>` is for structs (like `DateTime`) and value types like `int`, `float`, etc.